# Vue js cannot parse css codes in components

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue js + laravel to create a project. But I am facing an issue when I run `npm run watch` command.

Vue js throws the error below and the project does not build.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-8[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-8[0].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.url should be one of these:
   boolean | object { filter? }
   -> Allows to enables/disables `url()`/`image-set()` functions handling (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#url).
   Details:
* options.url should be a boolean.
* options.url should be an object:
  object { filter? }
at validate (/var/www/liaratech/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:105:11)
at Object.getOptions (/var/www/liaratech/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:527:19)
at Object.loader (/var/www/liaratech/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:31:27)
```

I realized that vue js cannot parse css codes in vue js component files.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Do you have CSS-Loader in your webpack config?
If so which version are you using? Can you show the config?
Also how and where are you importing the css file? I'm guessing it's the sweetalert2.min.css file, right?

Comment: I am using laravel-mix to compile assets.

Comment: Here's the import of css file
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

Comment: Yes. It is sweet alert

Comment: Do you have a postcss.config.js file for laravel mix?
What version are you using for laravel-mix and if you're using postcss what version are you using for that?

Comment: I haven't postcss.config.js file. laravel mix version is 6.0.6

Comment: I'm guessing here but it seems like there's a version mismatch for the css-loader.
You might have to add css-loader@^2.0.0 or css-loader@^3.0.0 to your devDependencies and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Yes. I added css-loader 3.0.0 to my devDependencies and now it is working. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help you.
Could you accept my answer I just added? That would be great :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is a version mismatch for css-loader.
Using css-loader@^3.0.0 fixes the problem (laravel-mix and sweetalert2 seem to use different versions I guess).

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "css-loader": "^3.0.0"
}
```